# Python 3 issue of unwanted brackets

Tags: python-3.6

if i print a variable containing an integer then why are brackets also printing in python 3.

Like this:-

```
count=5
a="The value of count is",count
print(a)
```

The output is like this:
('The value of count is', 5)

While I want the output to be like this:
The value of count is, 5

Actually I want to return the value of a so I have to do it like this only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a="The value of count is", count
```

Creates a tuple and puts it into `a`. Printing the tuple will add the parenthesis and comma.

Just concatenate the count to the message and print that instead:

```
a = "The value of count is " + str(count)
```

Or you could write it inline using f-strings:

```
print(f"The value of count is {count}")
```

Which is similar to your use of `format`.

Comment: I did it like this

a="The value of count is, {}".format(count)
is it correct?

Comment: @PiyushAgarwal Ya, you can do that too. I figured `format` would be overkill for this situation, but it's certainly ok.

Comment: Since this is tagged as Python 3.6, `print(f"The value of count is {count}")` is also an acceptable method

Comment: @Wondercricket I added a blurb. I was trying to KISS, but I suppose expanding a bit wouldn't hurt.